# How do I make shell remember things?

Tags: bash, notifications

So what this does (currently) is grab how many streamers are live. Let's say 2 of 5 are live, which works fine.

What I'd like to achieve is for those 2 streamers that are live to be "remembered" in a list without having to save it to a document.

So maybe a variable like $ListofStreamers and then I could use that in a pop-up dialogue of sorts to output the streamers that are live. Is there a way to do this without making a text file and saving whoever is live to it?

Thanks :D

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   Streamer=$(awk "NR==$i" $StreamersFile)
   Live=$(curl -i --header 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' --header "Client-ID: $TwitchAPI" "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/$Streamer" | grep -wo 'live') 
   if [ "$Live" == live ]; then \
      : $((LiveStreamers++))
   fi
done
```

Here's a rough idea of what I want.

```
for i in {1..$LiveStreamers}
do
  $Streamer$i
done

zenity --info --text=$Streamer1 $Streamer2 $Streamer3 $Streamer4 $Streamer5
```

But I want to put those streamers that are live into a single variable like a list.

Comment: Export to an environment variable.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. What do you mean by "remembered"? If you want it to persist after the script process ends, tough, you need to write it to a file. If you just want it to stick around while the script is executing, you're already setting two variables in your script, why won't setting another variable work? Please [edit] your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: I want it to save to a variable like $StreamersThatAreLive without having to make a variable for every line that a streamer is live. I don't know how to explain it further. Edited main post, no idea if it helps further

Comment: Array variable maybe?

Comment: @Interknet Yeah, I think that looks better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Looks like a very good candidate for a proper answer.

Comment: @8bittree I thought so, but I have a little knowledge about arrays and no time to learn right now. My answer would be mediocre quality at best. **Anyone can take the idea and write a good answer, I don't mind at all.** Maybe the OP will share his/her working solution.

Comment: Don't worry, about arrays and it works perfect. I'll edit into my main post what I did. New 'tool' for future scripts :D

Comment: You should really post your answer as an answer. Read: *[Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)* After you do this, rollback your question to the previous version so there's no answer in the question body. Let the question be a question only. This is how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@KamilMaciorowski** for the answer to use arrays. Here's the completed script:

```
    for i in {1..6}
do
   Streamer=$(awk "NR==$i" $StreamersFile)
   Live=$(curl -i --header 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' --header "Client-ID: $TwitchAPI" "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/$Streamer" | grep -wo 'live') 
   if [ "$Live" == live ]; then \
       StreamersThatAreLive=("${StreamersThatAreLive[@]}" "• $Streamer\n");
       List=${StreamersThatAreLive[@]}
   fi
done
zenity --info --text="Live right now:\n $List" --title="Live Right Now" 2> /dev/null
```

I'd explain how array's work, but I'm a newb to them. Here's the documentation I used which is super helpful: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial